# How do we disable Postgres database in Redash?

Tags: kubernetes, redash

We are exploring [Redash](https://redash.io/). For that, we deployed it as a Kubernetes service. Everything worked as expected. We also configured an external Postgres database instead of the embedded Postgres (which comes with Redash itself). It also worked as expected.

But now that we are using the external Postgres database we are trying to disable the internal database but somehow, we cannot do so. Every time we deploy Redash, it also creates a pod for internal Postgres (which we do not need now). Below is our `redash.yaml`

```
:
:
:
spec:
  externalPostgreSQL: EXTERNAL_POSTGRES
  externalPostgreSQLSecret: 
    name: postgres-secret
    key: EXTERNAL_POSTGRES
  postgresql:
    enabled: false        
:
:
:
```

As per the Redash documents that we read, this should be enough to disable the Postgres database.